# UICollectionViewLayout small and large cell auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewlayout

I have two cell sizes small (approx. half screen width before spacing and insets) and large (full screen width before insets), these two sizes can be seen in the following image.

[image: Problem]

I want the UICollectionView to automatically size these cell depending on a size attribute that is given. I have managed to size the cells correctly but I am having trouble getting the cells to layout correctly when there are not two small cells in sequence.

This is what happens when two small cells are in sequence in the array:

[image: Working]

This is where this cell should go:

[image]

Here is the custom UICollectionViewLayout's prepare function that I have made:

```
import UIKit

protocol FlexLayoutDelegate: class {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView:UICollectionView, sizeForViewAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> Int
}

class FlexLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    weak var delegate: FlexLayoutDelegate!

fileprivate var cellPadding: CGFloat = 10

fileprivate var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

fileprivate var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0

fileprivate var contentWidth: CGFloat {
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
        return 0
    }
    let insets = collectionView.contentInset
    return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
}

override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
}

override func prepare() {
    // Check if cache is empty
    guard cache.isEmpty == true, let collectionView = collectionView else {
        return
    }

    var yOffset = CGFloat(0)
    var xOffset = CGFloat(0)

    var column = 0

    for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {

        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)

        let viewSize: CGFloat = CGFloat(delegate.collectionView(collectionView, sizeForViewAtIndexPath: indexPath))

        let height = cellPadding * 2 + 240

        let width = contentWidth / viewSize
        if viewSize == 2 {
            xOffset = CGFloat(column) * width
        } else {
            xOffset = 0
        }

        print(width)

        let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: yOffset, width: width, height: height)
        let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)

        let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
        attributes.frame = insetFrame
        cache.append(attributes)

        contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
        column = column < 1 ? column + 1 : 0
        yOffset = column == 0 || getNextCellSize(currentCell: indexPath.row, collectionView: collectionView) == 1 ? yOffset + height : yOffset


    }
}

func getNextCellSize(currentCell: Int, collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    var nextViewSize = 0
    if currentCell < (collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) - 1) {
        nextViewSize = delegate.collectionView(collectionView, sizeForViewAtIndexPath: IndexPath(item: currentCell + 1, section: 0))
    }
    return nextViewSize
}

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

    var visibleLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    // Loop through the cache and look for items in the rect
    for attributes in cache {
        if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
            visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
        }
    }
    return visibleLayoutAttributes
}

override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    return cache[indexPath.item]
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: can you post the code for `getNextCellSize` method?

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot about that function, added @ReinierMelian

Comment: Sorry I had this done in my own code, but to adapt it to yours I need the implementation of your delegate, can you provide it?

Comment: I also need the definitions for `contentWidth` and `cellPadding`

Comment: I added the whole Layout File, so it is easier

Comment: OK, I will provide an answer soon @TomGrozev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an Array to track your columns heigths and see what is the shortest column that is `private var columsHeights : [CGFloat] = []`and you need also an array of `(Int,Float)` tuple to keep which spaces are available to be filled, I also added a method in the delegate to get the number of columns we want in the collection View and a method to know if a cell can be added or not in a position according their size.

Then if we want to add a cell we check if can be added if not, because the first column is filled we add the space corresponding to column2 in the `avaiableSpaces` array and when we add the next cell first we check if can be added in any available space if can be added we add and remove the available space.

**Here is the code**

> **FlexLayoutDelegate Implementation**

```
extension ViewController: FlexLayoutDelegate{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView:UICollectionView,sizeForViewAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) ->Int{
        if(indexPath.row % 2 == 1)
        {
            return 1
        }
        return 2
    }

    func numberOfColumnsInCollectionView(collectionView:UICollectionView) ->Int{
        return 2
    }
}
```

> **FlexLayout**

```
import UIKit

protocol FlexLayoutDelegate: class {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView:UICollectionView, sizeForViewAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> Int
    //  Returns the amount of columns that have to display at that moment
    func numberOfColumnsInCollectionView(collectionView:UICollectionView) ->Int
}

class FlexLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    weak var delegate: FlexLayoutDelegate!

    fileprivate var cellPadding: CGFloat = 10

    fileprivate var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    fileprivate var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
    private var columsHeights : [CGFloat] = []
    private var avaiableSpaces : [(Int,CGFloat)] = []

    fileprivate var contentWidth: CGFloat {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return 0
        }
        let insets = collectionView.contentInset
        return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
    }

    var columnsQuantity : Int{
        get{
            if(self.delegate != nil)
            {
                return (self.delegate?.numberOfColumnsInCollectionView(collectionView: self.collectionView!))!
            }
            return 0
        }
    }

    //MARK: PRIVATE METHODS
    private func shortestColumnIndex() -> Int{
        var retVal : Int = 0
        var shortestValue = MAXFLOAT

        var i = 0
        for columnHeight in columsHeights {
            //debugPrint("Column Height: \(columnHeight) index: \(i)")
            if(Float(columnHeight) < shortestValue)
            {
                shortestValue = Float(columnHeight)
                retVal = i
            }
            i += 1
        }
        //debugPrint("shortest Column index: \(retVal)")
        return retVal
    }

    private func canUseDoubleColumnOnIndex(columnIndex:Int) ->Bool
    {
        var retVal = false
        if(columnIndex < self.columnsQuantity-1)
        {
            let firstColumnHeight = columsHeights[columnIndex]
            let secondColumnHeight = columsHeights[columnIndex + 1]

            //debugPrint(firstColumnHeight - secondColumnHeight)
            retVal = firstColumnHeight == secondColumnHeight
        }

        return retVal
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }

    override func prepare() {
        // Check if cache is empty
        guard cache.isEmpty == true, let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return
        }

        //  Set all column heights to 0
        self.columsHeights = []
        for _ in 0..<self.columnsQuantity {
            self.columsHeights.append(0)
        }

        var xOffset = CGFloat(0)

        var column = 0

        for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {

            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)

            let viewSize: CGFloat = CGFloat(delegate.collectionView(collectionView, sizeForViewAtIndexPath: indexPath))

            let height = cellPadding * 2 + 240

            let width = contentWidth / viewSize
            if viewSize == 2 {
                xOffset = CGFloat(column) * width
            } else {
                xOffset = 0
            }

            var columIndex = self.shortestColumnIndex()
            var yOffset = self.columsHeights[columIndex]

            if(viewSize == 1){//Double Cell
                if(self.canUseDoubleColumnOnIndex(columnIndex: columIndex)){
                    //  Set column height
                    self.columsHeights[columIndex] = CGFloat(yOffset) + height
                    self.columsHeights[columIndex + 1] = CGFloat(yOffset) + height
                }else{
                    self.avaiableSpaces.append((columIndex,yOffset))
                    //  Set column height
                    yOffset += height
                    xOffset = 0
                    columIndex = 0
                    self.columsHeights[columIndex] = CGFloat(yOffset) + height
                    self.columsHeights[columIndex + 1] = CGFloat(yOffset) + height
                }
            }else{
                //if there is not avaiable space
                if(self.avaiableSpaces.count == 0)
                {
                    //  Set column height
                    self.columsHeights[columIndex] = CGFloat(yOffset) + height
                }else{//if there is some avaiable space

                    yOffset = self.avaiableSpaces.first!.1
                    xOffset = CGFloat(self.avaiableSpaces.first!.0) * width
                    self.avaiableSpaces.remove(at: 0)
                }
            }

            print(width)

            let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: yOffset, width: width, height: height)
            let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)

            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
            attributes.frame = insetFrame
            cache.append(attributes)

            contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
            column = column < 1 ? column + 1 : 0
            yOffset = column == 0 || getNextCellSize(currentCell: indexPath.row, collectionView: collectionView) == 1 ? yOffset + height : yOffset
        }
    }

    func getNextCellSize(currentCell: Int, collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        var nextViewSize = 0
        if currentCell < (collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) - 1) {
            nextViewSize = delegate.collectionView(collectionView, sizeForViewAtIndexPath: IndexPath(item: currentCell + 1, section: 0))
        }
        return nextViewSize
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        var visibleLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        // Loop through the cache and look for items in the rect
        for attributes in cache {
            if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
            }
        }
        return visibleLayoutAttributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cache[indexPath.item]
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this, now that I look at what you have done it makes so much sense. It was giving me a head ache just thinking about it but your example makes a lot of sense and even better, works very well! Thanks again